# Change home folder in Natty

Tags: 11.04, home-directory

Just now I made a fresh installation of Natty on my desktop. Earlier I was using Maverick with a separate home partition. While installing I selected `/` for maverick partition and selected nothing for earlier `home`. Now I noticed that earlier home is recognized as just another partition and a new `home` has been created. How can I set earlier `home` as `home` for natty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is really a good question, many people can face this problem,
see this link http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/separatehome this may help you.

an alternative reference to do the same thing: http://embraceubuntu.com/2006/01/29/move-home-to-its-own-partition/